# pyspark groupby agg with new col: diff between oldest and newest timetamp

Tags: pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe with the following columns:

- session_id
- timestamp

```
data = [(("ID1", "2021-12-10 10:00:00")), 
        (("ID1", "2021-12-10 10:05:00")),
        (("ID2", "2021-12-10 10:20:00")),
        (("ID2", "2021-12-10 10:24:00")),
        (("ID2", "2021-12-10 10:26:00")),
]
```

I would like to group sessions and add a new column called duration which would be the difference between oldest and newest timestamp for that session (in seconds):

```
ID1: 300
ID2: 360
```

How to achieve it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function like collect_list and then perform max and min operations on the list. To get duration in seconds, you can convert the time values to unix_timestamp and then perform the difference.

Try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    col,
    array_max,
    collect_list,
    array_min,
    unix_timestamp,
)

data = [
    ("ID1", "2021-12-10 10:00:00"),
    ("ID1", "2021-12-10 10:05:00"),
    ("ID2", "2021-12-10 10:20:00"),
    ("ID2", "2021-12-10 10:24:00"),
    ("ID2", "2021-12-10 10:26:00"),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["sessionId", "time"]).select(
    "sessionId", col("time").cast("timestamp")
)

df2 = (
    df.groupBy("sessionId")
    .agg(
        array_max(collect_list("time")).alias("max_time"),
        array_min(collect_list("time")).alias("min_time"),
    )
    .withColumn("duration", unix_timestamp("max_time") - unix_timestamp("min_time"))
)
df2.show()
```